# How to uniquely identify user logging in via oauth?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, openid

I particular - I don't understand how to link user that authenticated using oauth to a particular account in my application?

So here's accounts in my applciation:

```
CREATE TABLE accounts (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username VARCHAR(40),
    email VARCHAR(256),
    created DATETIME,
    updated DATETIME,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE KEY (email),
    UNIQUE KEY (username)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

With openid for example there is a unique **user id (uri, xri)** which uniquely identifies that user. So I can just link to my accounts like this:

```
CREATE TABLE openid_logins (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL auto_increment,
    fk_accounts_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    openid_identity TEXT NOT NULL, /*that's unique user id*/
    openid_provider_url VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,  /*flickr, yahoo, live_journal*/
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    INDEX (openid_identity),
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_accounts_id) REFERENCES accounts(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

So Whenever user logs in via openid -> I can get his regular account referencing fk_accounts_id.

But when it comes to oauth - AFAIK there is no such things as oauth_identity_string... And since oauth tokens might change tokens by themselves cannot be used as a unique link to profile in my applicaiton..... So what should I do? How to uniquely identify a user logging in via oauth?

Comment: Not all providers share the same idea of what is the user identifier as this identifier concept is not defined by OAuthxx. For example, for twitter, it's a number (there's no email). For most others, the email is the identifier, but there's no definite rule.

Comment: @SimonMourier Could you provide a concrete list of the providers and identifiers?

Comment: No, I can't.You'll have to browse developer documentation for each of the provider you're interested in (there is not even such a list of "most widely used" providers) and find out by reading and understanding their docs.

Answer (score 4):

You can't get information about the user by the OAuth protocol itself, however, there is normally an endpoint, to which you can make a request, that provides user information. For example Google provides one: after you receive your token, you can make a request to:

> GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token={TOKEN}

This will return a JSON object containing information about the user, including an unique identifier.

Comment: So what is the correct approach then? What's the use of a User table in your application if you can't tie it to the Oauth token? How do you know which application users are making model changes?

Answer (score 0):

Get the `account_id` using the apis and store it in the following format:

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table oauth -- its like a username passwd thingy
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS oauth (
  oauth_id                bigint unsigned     NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
  service                 varchar(16)         NOT NULL,
  account_id              varchar(256)        NOT NULL,
  token                   text                NOT NULL,
  token_secret            text                NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (service, account_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=ascii COLLATE=ascii_bin;
```

service can be a `google`, `twitter`, etc if you are using multiple oauth