# Uniquely identifying a user during the OAuth2 process

Tags: python, flask, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

I have made a flask/python website which can create and edit events on a user's google calendar. Obviously the user has to give their permission via OAuth2 (which I struggled to understand but managed to make work in the end). Currently I am forcing the user to register and login to my site and I store various user settings and the refresh token attached to whatever username they select when they register with my site.... But now I want the user to be able to allow the user the use my site without having to register. I still want to store user settings and a refresh token but now I need to have some sort of label to identify the user so I know it's them when they come back (perhaps they will access my site from a different PC). Is there some string that I will have access to as part of the OAuth2 process that would serve to uniquely identify the user or do I need to do some additional step to grab such a string...

**EDIT:** looking at the comment made by shox and looking at the most upvoted answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311836/how-to-identify-a-google-oauth2-user) it seems that at the end of the oauth process I should...

> send a GET to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo, using the
>   OAuth2 bearer token you just received, and you will get a response
>   with some information about the user (id, name, etc.).

Unfortunately I'm not quite sure what that means nor how to code it in python. My best guess was as follows:

```
r = requests.get( "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo",
                   params = {'token': credentials.token } )

data = r.json()
```

But data turns out to be `{'error': 'invalid_request', 'error_description': 'Invalid Credentials'}`

**SOLVED:** ... seems I needed to use the string "access_token" instead of "token" and now data contains an email address and a few other bits and bobs.

```
r = requests.get( "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo",
                   params = {'access_token': credentials.token } )

data = r.json()
```

Comment: Not part of the process but part of the endpoint. Which may be different for different providers. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21145560/how-to-uniquely-identify-user-logging-in-via-oauth

Answer (score 0):

One way to uniquely identify a Google user via OAuth 2.0 is to record the user's unique identifier. That identifier is known as the `id` property of the [Source](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#source) object.

To read that identifier you'll need to make a call to [`People.get()`](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get) with `people/me` as the `resourceName` and `metadata` as `personFields`. The first value will identify the authorized account as the one that we are interested in. In the second parameter, `personFields`, we are indicating that we want metadata about the target account. The latter isn't needed per se, but because we need to fill a valid value in `personFields`. In summary, the request should look like this (if done with [cURL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL)):

```
curl \
  'https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?personFields=metadata&key={API KEY}' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer {ACCESS TOKEN}' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed`
```

With that request you'll get a JSON response which first lines will read:

```
{
  "resourceName": "people/{ID HERE}",
  …
```

That would be the `id` that you want to use for user identification. Please, ask me any question if you need more help.

Comment: At a glance I get the feeling that the "People API" is something you may have access to if you have sought permission to have access to the users "contacts". I have not requested such permission so I suspect that this would not work. I have simply sought permission to access a users calendar.

Comment: Hi there @Mick! Please update your scopes and test if the solution works for you. Come back with your findings so I can keep helping you.